# Comma usage and properly identifying clauses in sentence

Tags: commas, clauses

I cannot figure out whether or not I need a comma between the word "cigarettes" and "according" in the following sentence:

> More college students are using marijuana daily than smoking
>   cigarettes according to a national survey released Tuesday.

My gut tells me the first clause is independent and the second dependent, which would mean I do not need a comma. Is this correct? Am I correct in thinking independent clause + dependent clause does not need a comma?

Comment: I'm wondering how one smokes cigarettes according to a survey, national or otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

You are certainly allowed a comma between an independent and dependent clause where there is large contrast. In this case, a comma appears appropriate.

You could also reword the sentence: According to a national survey added Tuesday, ...

Answer (score 1):

Generally (according to the [Oxford Dictionaries online](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/words/comma#commas_to_separate_clauses)):

> A comma marks a slight break between different parts of a sentence.
>   Used properly, commas make the meaning of sentences clear by grouping
>   and separating words, phrases, and clauses.

From the [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma#Separation_of_clauses) page:

> In English, a comma is used to separate a dependent clause from the
>   independent clause if the dependent clause comes first: After I fed
>   the cat, I brushed my clothes. (Compare this with I brushed my clothes
>   after I fed the cat.)

In your sentence:

- Independent clause: More college students are using marijuana daily than smoking cigarettes
- Dependent clause: according to a national survey released Tuesday

So, you can use a comma like this:

> More college students are using marijuana daily than smoking
>   cigarettes, according to a national survey released Tuesday.

Comment: although, when separating clauses, as opposed to phrases, or a clause and a phrase, a semi-colon should be used... At least according to what I vaguely remember from high school.